# Creating a vue.js component for a button group

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to create a webpage containing several button groups. The existing code is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-link").click(function() {
      console.log(this);
  });
});

Vue.component('nav-bar', {
    props: ['navs'],
    template: `<ul class="nav">
        <li v-for="nav in [{id: 0, text: 'Vege'}, {id:1, text: 'Ch'}]"
            v-bind:item="nav"
            v-bind:key="nav.id">
                <a class="nav-link" v-on:click="setactive($event)">{{ nav.text }}</a></li>
    </ul>`,
    methods: {
        setactive: function(event) {
            $(event.target).closest('ul').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
            $(event.target).addClass('active');
        },
    created: function() {
        $(this).find('a').first().addClass('active');
    }
    }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        navs: [
            { id: 0, text: 'Vegetables' },
            { id: 1, text: 'Cheese' },
            { id: 2, text: 'Milk' }
        ]
    }
});
```

```css
.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-link.active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
}
.nav-link {
    color: #4183c4;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <nav-bar></nav-bar>
</div>
```

My problems are:

- if changing `<li v-for="nav in [{id: 0, text: 'Vege'}, {id:1, text: 'Ch'}]"` to `<li v-for="nav in navs"`, nothing is displayed at all. Whats wrong with that?
- why isn't the first item's class set to `active` upon creation?
- how can the nav items be given directly to `<nav-bar>`?

I do not want to use `bootstrap` button-groups.

Comment: I did not mean to give this impression. I have read the tutorial at vue.org, though not to the end. Nevertheless, I will try to refine my question.

Comment: I read more documentation, hoping that the example now contains the basics of Vue.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if changing `<li v-for="nav in [{id: 0, text: 'Vege'}, {id:1, text: 'Ch'}]"` to `<li v-for="nav in navs"`, nothing is displayed at all. Whats wrong with that?

That depends on the value of `navs`. We'd need to see the exact code to troubleshoot.

> how can the nav items be given directly to `<nav-bar>`?

To pass the value of `navs` from `App` to `<nav-bar>`, use [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind):

```
<div id="app">
  <nav-bar v-bind:navs="navs" />

  <!-- OR shorthand for v-bind -->
  <nav-bar :navs="navs" />
</div>
```

> why isn't the first item's class set to `active` upon creation?

The DOM hasn't yet been stamped in the `created` lifecycle hook, so jQuery isn't able to find the element to set active. Since the elements you're querying are dynamically added (via the `navs` prop), you'd have to:

1. Wait until the `navs` prop changes (instead of using a lifecycle hook). Use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) for this:

   ```
   Vue.component('nav-bar', {
     watch: {
       navs: {
         handler() { /* SEE NEXT STEP */ },
         immediate: true, // call handler immediately in case `navs` data is already available
       }
     }
   })
   ```
2. Wait until the elements are added to the DOM in [`$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick).

   ```
   // in watch:
   handler() {
     this.$nextTick(() => {
       $(this).find('a').first().addClass('active');
     });
   },
   ```

```js
Vue.component('nav-bar', {
  props: ['navs'],
  template: `<ul class="nav" ref="list">
        <li v-for="nav in navs"
            v-bind:item="nav"
            v-bind:key="nav.id">
          <a class="nav-link" v-on:click="setactive($event)">{{ nav.text }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>`,
  methods: {
    setactive: function(event) {
      $(event.target).closest('ul').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
      $(event.target).addClass('active');
    },
  },
  watch: {
    navs: {
      immediate: true,
      handler() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          $(this.$refs.list).find('a').first().addClass('active');
        });
      }
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    navs: [{
        id: 0,
        text: 'Vegetables'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Cheese'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Milk'
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-link.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #4183c4;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <nav-bar :navs="navs"></nav-bar>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Would never have used `nextTick()`... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you also have an idea how to substitute `$(".nav-link").click(function()...` by `$(".nav-bar").click(function()...` as `<a class="nav-link">` is not visible from the outside? The click event does not seem to bubble upwards to its parent, if I am doing this substitution...

Comment: @Markus No problem :) Regarding the second problem, it would be best to ask that as a new question, so that someone familiar with the topic could answer you.